# While installing customer registration fields getting the following error

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting the error while installing the following extension:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custome-account-profile-13594.html. After the extension has been successfully installed the following error is occurred. "
Fatal error: Class 'Amar_Profile_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\porto\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234"